# javascript module pattern context issue

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble learning the module pattern,

what is the correct way to be able to run my function  getData from within Setup currently it is undefined.

https://jsbin.com/movaleyedo/edit?html,js,console,output

```js
var module = (function(){
  var Setup = function(){
    this.getData = function(){
      return "data";
    };
    this.init = function(){
      
      this.getData(function(err,data){
         alert(data);
      });
    };
  };
  return {
    init: new Setup().init
  };
})();
module.init();
```

```
"TypeError: this.getData is not a function
at Object.init (movaleyedo.js:8:12)
at movaleyedo.js:17:8
at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.9.min.js:1:13891
at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-3.35.9.min.js:1:10820"
```

I have created a second example, of why I do not understand what is going on.

```js
var Module = (function(){
  var app = this;
  var One = function(){
    this.one = function(){
      return 1;
    }
    this.getNumbers = function(){
      return this.one();
    }
  };
  
  var Two = function(){
    this.getNumbers = function(){
      return 2;
    }
    this.two = function(){
      app.one = new One;
      console.log(app.one.getNumbers()); //doesnt break
      console.log(this.getNumbers());//breaks
    }
  };
  
  return {
    init: new Two().two
  };
  
})();
Module.two();
```

Basically inside One(), I can call return this.one().

but inside Two() i cannot call this.getNumbers()

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question (inline). If you *need* to run something, [Stack Snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) are available.

Comment: `this` is not what you want it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implementation is sync, invocation is async

```
this.getData = function(){
  return "data";
};

this.getData(function(err,data){
   alert(data);
});

//should be used either
var data = this.getData();
alert(data);

//or defined as

this.getData = function(callback){
  callback(null, "data");
};
```

also that other user was right, you are passing only the function. And using the "this" keyword in that function will reference something else. why not pass the instance itself or create instance?

something like this

```
return new Setup();

module.init();
```

or

```
return Setup;

var instance = new module();
instance.init();
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you enter this.init, you've changed contexts and `this` no longer points to the object you're constructing.  To solve this, you can cache `this` in a variable at the top of your constructor for later reference:

```js
var module = (function(){
  var self = this;   // <------ Add this line
  var Setup = function(){
    this.getData = function(){
      return "data";
    };
    this.init = function(){
      
      self.getData(function(err,data){  // <------ update this line
         alert(data);
      });
    };
  };
  return {
    init: new Setup().init
  };
})();
module.init();
```

You are also passing getData() a callback that it doesn't call.  You should review user1695032s answer as well